# Adding a New REST Service Project to an ASP.Net MVC SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, telerik-reporting

I have been developing an ASP.Net Core 2.0 SPA web application in Visual Studio 2017 which started life using the new Angular SPA Template ([ASP.Net Core SPA Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio)). I now need to add reporting to the website and the Telerik Reporting solution I am trying requires a REST Service to function.

Telerik provide a VS 2017 template for their REST Service which I used to add a new .Net 4.6.1 Project to my Solution with its own `ReportsController` and associated references and code etc. The Telerik REST Service requires the full .Net framework.

My solution builds and runs, I can view my Angular web application, but if I use Postman to send a request to the new `ReportsController` I just get a `500 server error`. I have added a reference in my SPA project to the REST Service project, which I may not require. Should I somehow configure the new REST Service in my SPA project's `startup` class?

How do I configure my solution such that the new REST Service is launched and listening for requests from my Angular web application please?

Comment: Are they in separate projects? Within the same solution?

Comment: A 500 error normally means the request got to the server and there was an error on the server.  If you were not connecting to the server at all then you would get a 404 not a 500.

Comment: SSharp - I have a single VS Solution with 2 Projects; ASP.Net MVC SPA Project (ASP.Net Core 2.0), Telerik REST Service (.Net 4.6.1).

Comment: nurdyguy - My ASP.Net MVC Project has its own Web API Controllers listening for requests from my Angular web application. I imagine that my request for `api/reports` is attempting to be handled by this and responding with a `500 error`. I can't simply add the `ReportsController` to this project as it requires full `.Net` framework.